# In Slick 3, how does one SQL-Compile an insert using a mapped case class?

Tags: scala, slick

To SQL-compile a query, you need to compile a function which takes, for each query parameter `arg: type`, a lifted parameter of type `Rep[type]` .

I have a case class `JobRecord` and a TableQuery `jobRecords`.

So to insert a JobRecord case-class instance, I need to be able to say something like:

```
val qMapToId = (jobRecords returning jobRecords.map(_.id))
def ucCreate(jobRecord: Rep[JobRecord]) = qMapToId += jobRecord
val cCreate = Compiled(ucCreate _)
```

But of course this doesn't compile, because += doesn't take a Rep, and I'm not sure Rep[JobRecord] is valid either.

I've tried many things, not worth showing, including mixing in the [Monomorphic Case Classes](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0-RC3/userdefined.html#monomorphic-case-classes) guidance.  I probably got a step away from a solution a few times.  A pointer to a working example would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to do anything, `val qMapToId = (jobRecords returning jobRecords.map(_.id))` generates the statement once, at compile time (i.e. on container startup).

`Compiled` replaces `Parameters` in the new API, and comes into play for selects, updates, and (I believe) deletes where you are binding placeholders for generating a prepared statement. For insert statements there's nothing to bind, you already have an instance for `+=`.

Comment: In the documentation, on their website, it says _You can use a compiled query for querying, inserting, updating and deleting data._ This is either misleading or doesn't correspond with what you're saying.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TableQuery[] as follows.

```
# define TableQuery of JobRecord
case class JobRecordRow(...)
class JobRecord(tag:Tag) extends Table[JobRecordRow](tag, "JOB_TABLE_NAME") {
}
# define compiled query
val insert = Compiled( TableQuery[JobRecord].filter(_ => true:Rep[Boolean]))
val stmt = (insert += JobRecordRow(...))
db.run( stmt)
```

The Compiled query seems little bit tricky. However, when I tried `Compiled(TableQuery[JobRecord])` as suggested in other articles, it did not work. By adding `filter()`, I could build insert query.

Updated on 2019-07-21

Instead of `filter()`, `map(identity)` can be used.

```
TableQuery[JobRecord].map(identity)
```